# Echo Uncaught Exception

Tags: php, sha256, bitcoin

I am making a bitcoin faucet using the coinbase api, and was looking to validate the address. I looked online to see if there are any good scripts, and couldnt find any so I decided to test and see if it was already built in the API, and it was! The the thing is that instead of just saying that is not a valid address it php displays a LONG error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Coinbase_ApiException' with message 'Please enter a valid email or bitcoin address' in C:\xampp\htdocs\nahtnam\lib\Coinbase\Rpc.php:84 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\nahtnam\lib\Coinbase\Coinbase.php(39): Coinbase_Rpc->request('POST', 'transactions/se...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\nahtnam\lib\Coinbase\Coinbase.php(118): Coinbase->post('transactions/se...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\nahtnam\faucet.php(54): Coinbase->sendMoney('17FSKMPAyXGR7EQ...', '0.00000555', 'this is a test') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\nahtnam\lib\Coinbase\Rpc.php on line 84

Is ther any way i can just set $address_error to "Please enter a valid Address" (not email) if this occurs and also not display the error? Thanks!

Comment: You should use `try ... catch` to catch the error and display the message nicely to the user.

Comment: This should help http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: more code here , i mean request bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [aliasm2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680121/3240), you probably want to do it more like this:

**EDIT: Changed answer slightly based on comments discussion**

I think I was a bit unclear on what you were asking for in the comments.

```php
 try {
     $result = $Coinbase->sendMoney($bitcoinaddress, '0.00000555', 'this is a test');
 catch(Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage(); 
     exit;   //optional but you probably want to quit here and show the user
             //the original form along with the error message to fix 
 }
```

This is just going to echo "Please enter a valid email or bitcoin address." You wont get all of that other info because you are catching the exception and  just displaying the message. 
Possible error messages [are listed here](https://coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/transactions/send_money.html).

Also, if I can give you a slightly off-topic hint:
If you want to find info about a particular address that has been used, try the [blockchain block explorer api](http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api).

And to simply check if an address is valid, you need to calculate that in your code or find a library function to do so. There's no master-list of addresses that an api would have. The last 4 bytes of the address are a double-sha-256 checksum of the preceding characters. That's sort-of an imprecise description I'm giving you, by the way,  but check [here for a working php example](https://github.com/Xenland/Bitcoin-Pseudocode-Client/blob/gh-pages/examples/php/verify_bitcoin_address.php)

Comment: Hi, I know about the blockchain api, but the thing is that coinbase pays the fees for you... Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: Roger that. I just meant you could use blockchain for verification In addition to coinbase for the transaction.

Comment: In the exception area, can I just do $address_error = "please enter a valid bitcoin address!" and remove the echo? Also what do you think of this design? http://puu.sh/4mlzx.png Thanks!

Comment: It might be better to determine what the exact exception code is first then you can handle it how you want.     But when you catch the exception the program flow continues so you also want to exit the script from there and put the user back on the initial form with the error message see edit above.

Comment: Hmmm. I am getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\nahtnam\faucet.php on line 81" when i type this code: http://imgur.com/uFaThjF Sorry, im being a total n00b at this you will know why if you go here: http://nahtnam.com

Comment: There's no if to go with the else in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Use `try` and `catch`.

```
try {
    if(/*invalid address check returns true*/)
        throw 'Invalid address';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```